# How can I extract information from an input file and put them in an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file, io

I have an input.txt file:

- First line: `m` and on the following `m` lines I have pairs of 2 numbers `a` and `n`

I have to calculate a^n and the result can have max 10^8 digits. I made the program using arrays and giving values to `a` and `n`. It returned the correct answer. But what I have to do is to read the information from the file, calculate a^n and write the numbers in an output.txt file.

Example:

In input.txt I have on the first line

```
2
2 10
1 100000
```

output.txt

```
1024
1
```

As I said, the program works with any numbers wrote by me in the main program. Now I need help to extract the numbers from input.txt, put them in array and after I calculate them to return them in output.txt.

---

#### Non-compiling code copied from codepad.org

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int MAX_NR_DIGITS = 10000;

void longNumClone(char *from, char *to)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NR_DIGITS; i++)
        to[i] = from[i];
}

void longNumPrint(char *num, int sizeNum) {
    int i;
    for (i = sizeNum-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%i", num[i]);
    }
}

int longNumDiv2(char *rez, char *num, int sizeNum) {
    int i;
    num[sizeNum] = 0;
    rez[sizeNum] = 0;

    for (i = sizeNum - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        rez[i] = ((num[i+1] - rez[i+1]*2) * 10 + num[i]) / 2;
    }

    if (rez[sizeNum - 1] == 0) {
        return sizeNum - 1;
    }
    return sizeNum;
}

int multiply(char *rez, char *a, int sizeA, char *b, int sizeB) {
    int sizeRez = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NR_DIGITS; i++) {
        rez[i] = 0;
    }

    int temp = 0, j;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeB; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < sizeA; j++) {
            temp = b[i] * a[j];

            int inc = 0;
            do {
                temp = temp + rez[i + j + inc];
                rez[i + j + inc] = temp % 10;
                if (i + j + inc + 1 > sizeRez) {
                    sizeRez = i + j + inc + 1;
                }
                temp = temp / 10;
                inc++;
            }while (temp != 0);
        }
    }

    return sizeRez;
}

int superpow(char *rez, char *base, int sizeBase, char *exp, int sizeExp) {
    int i;
    char temp[MAX_NR_DIGITS];
    char temp1[MAX_NR_DIGITS];
    char temp2[MAX_NR_DIGITS];

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NR_DIGITS; i++) {
        rez[i] = 0;
    }

    int sizeRez = 1;
    rez[0] = 1;

    while (sizeExp > 0) {
        if (exp[0] & 1) {
            longNumClone(rez, temp);
            sizeRez = multiply(rez, temp, sizeRez, base, sizeBase);
        }

        longNumClone(exp, temp);
        sizeExp = longNumDiv2(exp, temp, sizeExp);

        longNumClone(base, temp1);
        longNumClone(base, temp2);
        sizeBase = multiply(base, temp1, sizeBase, temp2, sizeBase);

          }

    return sizeRez;
}

int main() {

    // 4437053125^625
    char a[MAX_NR_DIGITS] = {5, 2, 1, 3, 5, 0, 7, 3, 4, 4};
    int sizeA = 10;
    char n[MAX_NR_DIGITS] = {5, 2, 6};
    int sizeN = 3;

      char rez[MAX_NR_DIGITS];
    int sizeRez = 0;


    sizeRez = superpow(rez, a, sizeA, n, sizeN);
    longNumPrint(rez, sizeRez);

    return 0;
}
```

The arrays in `main()` are deemed variable-length arrays (VLAs) because `MAX_NR_DIGITS` is not deemed to be an integer constant expression, and you can't initialize VLAs.  It would be OK in C++, but not in C.

Comment: where's the code?

Comment: What parts of the task are you having trouble with? File I/O? Dynamic memory allocation? We are not here to just do your homework

Comment: @ZachP: please read first: he needs help "**to extract the numbers, put them in a array and [...] calculate them to output them in output.txt**"

Comment: Code please, and we will help.

Comment: @RoadRunner  http://codepad.org/M5oMbLDh This is the code

Comment: @Radinator I read everything, how does what you quoted disregard my criticism? Extracting the numbers is simple file I/O, putting them in an array just concludes of dynamic memory allocation, calculation is simple and he says he already has that implemented and outputting them to a file is still just file I/O...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  We'll help you fix your code; we won't write your program for you.  I'm worried about your "max 10^8 digits"; did you mean the maximum value will be `1E8` or 10^8, so it fits easily in a 32-bit `int`?  Or did you really mean 100 million decimal digits (which is what you seem to say), in which case, you're into dealing with 'big numbers'.  I assume it is actually the simpler "it fits in a 32-bit `int`" scenario.

Comment: @EmmanuelBan first of all I'd fix the warnings.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes, the result can have maximum 100 million digits, that's why I worked with array. I'm in first year of university and started with C, something I never studied. The program works!!! The problem is I don't know how to read caracters from input.txt, put them in array and after calculating a^n with the program putting the results in output.txt.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=read+numbers+from+a+text+file+in+C

Comment: Just one of zillions of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20378430/694576

Answer (score 0):

Look into [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) for reading a certain format from a file, and [fprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/?kw=fprintf) for writing a certain format to a file.

An example given some initialised `FILE *read_file` and `FILE *write_file` could be

```
int count, int a, n;
fscanf(read_file, "%d ", &count);

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    fscanf(read_file, "%d %d ", &a, &n);
    ... 
    /* calculate the output result */
    ...
    fprintf(write_file, "%d\n", result);
}
```